# How to query first 5 rows of a mysql table

Tags: mysql

I know that I can query a range of ids using BETWEEN command but there is a situation that the id of first 5 rows are like this: 1,5,6,7,8

In this situation if I query using BETWEEN command I will get 1,5.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I promise you, this is all covered in the manual. It's surprisingly readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select * from mytable
order by id
limit 5
```

You need `order by` to give an order to the rows. Without `order by`, rows have no defined order.

——

To return 5 rows starting from the nth row:

```
...
limit n, 5
```

Comment: And what if I want to query second 5 rows?